# mongoose /node.js - update an object inside a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following MongoDB collection:

```
user: "user123",
array1 = [
     {
     id: 1,
     active: true
     },
     {
     id: 2,
     active: true
     }
],
array2 = [
     {
     id: 3,
     active: true
     },
     {
     id: 4,
     active: true
     }
],
array3 = [
     {
     id: 5,
     active: true
     },
     {
     id: 6,
     active: true
     }
]
```

i need to update active to be false.
i am given the user, the array to update and also the id dynamically from the client.
so lets say for example i have following variables

```
let arrayToUpdate = 'array1'
let idToUpdate = 2
let user = 'user123'
```

according to mongoose docs i need to use the following method:

```
   const query = { user: user, "arrayToUpdate.id": idToUpdate}; //the problem is here
    const updateDocument = {
      $set: { "arrayToUpdate.$.active": "false" }
    };
    const result = await AutoUsersPositions.updateOne(query, updateDocument);
```

my problem is that the 2nd arguemnt of the query (arrayToUpdate.id) have to be inside "" which means i cant use it dynamically. i tried using `${}` but it didnt work.
the same problem might be happening also on the $set part.
any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to generate dynamic key names, you just need to define the string first:

```
const arrayUpdateKey = `arrayToUpdate.${id}`
const query = { user: user, [arrayUpdateKey]: idToUpdate};
```